# Correct usage of <strong> and <small> tags when used together

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Giving that both `<strong>` and `<small>` tags are inline, which usage should be considered as correct semantically?

Case 1:

```
<strong><small>Some text</small></strong>
```

Case 2:

```
<small><strong>Some text</strong></small>
```

Does it matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who has ever done search engine optimisation would know `h1` tag makes whole hell of a lot of difference between ranked on page 1 to page 30. So yes these tags do have their importance but how?
I am copy pasting official explanation and my subsequent question is underneath.

> `<b>` vs. `<strong>`
>
> It is often confusing to new developers why there are so many ways to
> express the same thing on a rendered website.  and  are
> perhaps one of the most common sources of confusion, causing
> developers to ask "Should I use  or ? Don't they both do
> the same thing?"
>
> Not exactly. The  element is for content that is of greater
> importance, while the  element is used to draw attention to text
> without indicating that it's more important.
>
> It may help to realize that both are valid and semantic elements in
> HTML5 and that it's a coincidence that they both have the same default
> styling (boldface) in most browsers (although some older browsers
> actually underline ). Each element is meant to be used in
> certain types of scenarios, and if you want to bold text for
> decoration, you should instead actually use the CSS font-weight
> property.
>
> The intended meaning or purpose of the enclosed text should be what
> determines which element you use. Communicating meaning is what
> semantics are all about.
>
> `<em>` vs. `<strong>`
>
> Adding to the confusion is the fact that while HTML
> 4 defined  as indicating a stronger emphasis, HTML 5 defines
>  as representing "strong importance for its contents." This is
> an important distinction to make.
>
> While  is used to change the meaning of a sentence as spoken
> emphasis does ("I love carrots" vs. "I love carrots"),  is
> used to give portions of a sentence added importance (e.g., "Warning!
> This is very dangerous.") Both  and  can be nested to
> increase the relative degree of importance or stress emphasis,
> respectively.
>
> The HTML <`small>` element represents side-comments and small print,
> like copyright and legal text, independent of its styled presentation.
> By default, it renders text within it one font-size smaller, such as
> from small to x-small.

The question is if all of them have predefined behaviour and don't do anything other than visual appeal. Since Bold means important and strong means important visually speaking. then who is this behaviour targeted to. We don't usually go looking in source code do we?

Answer is BOTS and most importantly indexing, scraping BOTS. If you are doing SEO and some kind of content analytics or parsing this from that then these tags come handy. Other than that its no different than

```
<i><b>hello</b></i>
```

or

```
<b><i>hello</i></b>
```

or

```
<small><strong>hello</strong></small>
```

or

```
<strong><small>hello</small></strong>
```

Yes they do matter depending on your case to case basis. Other than visual human reads if I am expecting lot of computer readability such text to speech, or bots, or assisted display etc then these matter.

bold: tag my dad telling me to do something

strong: tag my dad telling me to do something in firm instructive voice

italic: its part of content but not flow of content doesn't matter if you missed it

small: its part of content but not flow of content but if you missed it we might come back to say you should have read it.

Within content marketing perspective above distinctions play a major role with in source code which computers are going to parse.

Comment: This answer could be improved by making it more directly related to the question of semantics, and not SEO.

Comment: It was more of a opening starter line attempting to differentiate between visuals from programming interpretations for the term semantics. This had been the theme of question and consequent answer as stated above. Reference to H1 is fine example in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter.

`<strong>` produces `font-weight: bold;` and `<small>` produces `font-size: smaller;`, neither of which overrides eachother.

Comment: My question is not about what styles are applied, I am rather interested in the semantics.

Comment: But that does not matter, if neither of the two elements styling overrides either of which?

Comment: The `<strong>` element is for content that is of "strong importance". The `<small>` element represents side-comments and small print. So which one wins?

Comment: Again, neither... because they're not related to each other in any sense.

Comment: Hm, how can they not be related when used together? Am I missing something?

Comment: Using `<strong>` and `<small>` together is equivalent to using `<i>` and `<b>` together. They serve their own purposes and neither of them overrides anything set by the other element.

Comment: This question is about semantics, not styling.

Answer (score 1):

From a **syntactic** standpoint, either can be used. Since both are [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) elements that can contain other phrasing content, they're both equally valid HTML.

---

From a **semantic** standpoint, be sure you're using each tag appropriately:

[**`<small>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small) should not be used to style text smaller. It should only be used to provide semantic meaning to—

> ...side-comments and small print, like copyright and legal text, independent of its styled presentation.

Likewise, [**`<strong>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) should not be used to make text bold. It should only be used to indicate—

> ...that its contents have strong importance, seriousness, or urgency.

These tags should also not encompass more than they need to. For instance, you might have might have legal text like this, where only a portion of the text has strong importance:

```html
<p><small>Copyright Foobar Industries, 2021. <strong>Do not reprint without permission.</strong></small></p>
```

If the *entirety* of your side-comments or small print is of strong importance, you can use either approach. They are semantically equivalent and syntactically valid.

Answer (score -1):

**Some text**

**Some text**

Both of them will do the same thing. It will bold the text and lower its font size.

Comment: My question is not about what styles are applied, I am rather interested in the semantics.

Comment: how is your answer different oder better than the already given ones?